# jquery validation statement not working

Tags: jquery, validation

I am having problems with my jQuery password validation statement. I cannot pinpoint the problem even after debugging.Im not sure if its the vars uc, lc and nm but agin, no errors when debugging, any help ?

```
var pFields = $('#pword1, #pword2'),
    p1 = $('#pword1'),
    p2 = $('#pword2'),
    p1Val = p1.val(),
    p2Val = p2.val();

var uc = (p1Val.match(/[A-Z]/)) ? 1 : 0,
    lc = (p1Val.match(/[a-z]/)) ? 1 : 0,
    nm = (p1Val.match(/[0-9]/)) ? 1 : 0;


pFields.on('blur', function() {

    if(p1Val == "") {

        p1.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        alert('p1 is empty');
    } else if(p2Val == "") {

        p2.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        alert('p2 is empty');
    } else if(p1Val != p2Val) {

        pFields.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        alert('p fields do not match');
    } else if(!uc) {

        p1.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        alert('add a uc');
    } else if(!lc) {

        p1.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        alert('add a lc');
    } else if(!nm) {

        p1.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        alert('add a nm');
    } else {

        pFields.removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your variables (input fields values) are set on app init. So `.on('blur')` even if your input fields are filled in, you're checking variables instead of input fields values.

Put variables in `.on('blur')` scope:

```
var pFields = $('#pword1, #pword2'),
    p1      = $('#pword1'),
    p2      = $('#pword2');

pFields.on('blur', function() {

    var p1Val = p1.val(),
        p2Val = p2.val(), 
        uc    = (p1Val.match(/[A-Z]/)) ? 1 : 0,
        lc    = (p1Val.match(/[a-z]/)) ? 1 : 0,
        nm    = (p1Val.match(/[0-9]/)) ? 1 : 0;

    //... rest of your code ...
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/sbe8ouh5/)

Comment: I feel stupid now. How did I not notice this. Thankyou anyway!